# Flutter: Build child depending on visibility

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Assume I have an app where you can zoom in and out. The zooming is managed by a Transform Widget.

Now, if you zoom in, I want to load more details by expanding the Widget tree, and when zooming out I want to remove these too-tiny-to-be-seen Widgets again.

So, I’d like to have a fixed-size Widget that gets a lambda to build a child depending on:
- being seen on the screen
- actual pixel size

Comment: rebuild your widget tree when zooming in/out (for example inside `GestureDetector#onScaleUpdate`)

Comment: @pskink I need a way to measure the patent to decide if to dynamically build the child or not.

Comment: see `MatrixUtils` then

Comment: @pskink it’s a recursive tree with potentially many transformations.

Comment: @pskink probably I can use https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomSingleChildLayout-class.html

Comment: i have no idea what you mean by `"a recursive tree with potentially many transformations"`, sorry

Comment: @pskink probably to rephrase it simpler: I need a Widget X that delegates building its only child C to a function that depends on the on-screen size of X.

Comment: post your existing code then

Comment: @pskink sorry, I am in the concept stage. Can build of a Widget gets its own size?

Comment: how can you get the size if you did not build your widget yet?

Comment: @pskink that’s point I think, so I need to do this “asynchronous”, i.e. measure the patent after the layouting phase and then conditionally enable the child via setState

Comment: sorry, again i have no idea what "patent" you mean... what do you want to achieve actually?

Comment: @pskink I meant parent, not patent. Okay, think about a floor-plan where you can zoom into a room. You only wanted to build the room if it is large enough.

Comment: @pskink it looks like this should work: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html

Comment: so as you said you will use `Transform` widget - it uses `Matrix4` parameter and as i said use `MatrixUtils` to check how large is some unit after tranforming with `Matrix4`

Comment: @pskink I got that, however the Transform Widget might be sitting much higher in the Widget tree, and I might have multiple ones. I hope that the LayoutBuilder gives me the size in pixels after all transformations along the path were applied.

Comment: i dont think so - imho `LayoutBuilder` does not respect any `Transform` widgets - but i may be wrong here too...

Comment: @pskink I think you are right. From the docs of RotatedBox, I get that Transform only applies at painting time. So, it’s not suitable for culling.